# JWT implementation in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I want to store JWT token in database with TTL Value as expiration.So whenever client makes a request with the token, he updates the TTL value to prolong the session.To expire the session he just deletes the TTL from db. To login again he will check the TTL present or not against his token if it is present he will be able to login.
Is this the best way to implement.What is the better way , any suggestions ?

Note: I do not want to use auth0 or oauth 2.0 .

Why storing token in DB ?

Instead of validating against username and password every request i can just check the token alone . And I do not set any expiration for my JWT Token . Why data store in my case is to maintain session across different nodes

Comment: The whole purpose of JWT is that you don't need any persistent data store. Why are you storing tokens in a database?

Comment: Instead of validating against username and password every request i can just check the token alone . And I do not set any expiration for my JWT Token . Why data store in my case  is to maintain session across different nodes

Comment: (1) The signed JWT will maintain the session for you, without any data in the database. (2) If you need extra data to be stored (like a shopping cart or something) then JWT does not offer you any benefit here and you should just use a traditional unsigned session mechanism. The entire purpose of JWT is to be independently verifiable without a central session store; using a session store negates the entire benefit of JWT.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to tweak your architecture a little I would suggest you use redis for storing token, instead of JWT you could keep it key:value pair.

Here key could be an uniqueID like **dkajd4165f6asdfgd4as** and value can be all data that you've stored in JWT in form of a JSON example

```
{
    userName:"XYZ",
    sessionValid:true
}
```

Every entry in redis can have a TTL value and it can also be changed or destroyed explicitly as required by you. This will also separate your main database from session managing database(i.e. redis) and give you control over session management without querying your main database.

For detailed documentation you can  visit it's official [documentation](https://redis.io/documentation)

If you want to try it out you can check [this](https://try.redis.io/) this can work as step by step guide to basics of using redis.

NOTE : This approach is not using JWT instead answers your question to suggest another approach to do it.